# How to create breadcrumb in my view function?

Tags: django

*(By chance, I removed my last question)*

How to create breadcrumb in my view function?

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Name')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Name')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    #category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name=u'Category')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

#views
def post_content(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id = product_id)
    return render_to_response('product_info.html', {'product':product},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

product_info.html

```
{{ product.name }}
```

I want in my single post info (`post_content`) breadcrumb with category.
Something like this:  Category > Subcategory > Sub-Subcategory .,,,

Someone told me to use get_ancestors:

Example:

```
{% for parent in category.get_ancestors %}
  <a href="{{ parent }}">{{ parent.name }}</a> &gt;
{% endfor %}
{{ category.name }}
```

How to implement this with my model?

Thank you. I would be grateful.

Comment: Your product can belong to multiple categories (`ManyToManyField`). So what breadcrumb you expect from product?

Comment: Sorry. Suppose that it is ForeignKey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `category = models.ForeignKey(Category)`, just do:

```
{% for parent in product.category.get_ancestors %}
  <a href="{{ define_url_to_parent }}">{{ parent.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```